# Print Spring Http Response with log4j to console

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

How can I configure *log4j.properties* to automatically pretty print the servlet response body(json) to eclipse/terminal console (wire to DEBUG).

This is a Spring(4.3.3) Rest project which produces JSON response. Have `jackson-databind`(2.5.0) in pom.xml, to convert a model object to json string.

Controller

```
@RestController
public class ControllerClass {
  public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ControllerClass.class);

  @Postmapping("link")
  ResponseModel method (@RequestBody ....){
    ResponseModel model ;
    // other code
    return model;
  }
}
```

log4j.properties (log4j 1.2.17)

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, ERROR, stdout, DEBUG    
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n
```

Need to wire HTTP response to log4j DEBUG so that the response can be automatically printed ( **not by calling** `logger.debug()` )

**Note :**  There is a filter which extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` as part of Spring security in my project. If no other option, is it good way to put command to print Response body after `chain.doFilter()`?

Comment: You have to call logger.debug() somewhere. Why do you not want to call logger.debug() ? Worrying about performance ?

Comment: Querying on if there is any configuration in log4j/Spring so that the response can be wired to debug. Anyway i can switch to using `logger.debug()` in my filter. Thanks @rajind-ruparathna for your response